# The gap of two JDBC for Oracle statements performance is so huge

Tags: oracle, performance, jdbc

This is my code, it is very slowly when using prepareStatement to send `rq` dynamically

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    String sql = "select KHDM from T_KHZHYKQK where khdm= '10797684' and zjzhlxdm = '0' and rq >= '20191230' and rq <= '20210104' order by rq";
    String sql2 = "select KHDM from T_KHZHYKQK where khdm = '10797684' and zjzhlxdm = '0' and rq >= ? and rq <= ? order by rq";
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        statement.executeQuery(sql);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("time1:" + (end - start));
    }
    System.out.println();

    preStmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        preStmt.setString(1, "20191230");
        preStmt.setString(2, "20210104");
        preStmt.executeQuery();
        long end1= System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("time2:" + (end1 - start1));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

this is the result, the gap of two statements performance is so huge.

```
time1:206
time1:108
time1:110
time1:109
time1:111

time2:7752
time2:7372
time2:7029
time2:6961
time2:7105
```

`rq` is  `RQ        NUMBER(8)     default 0 not null`  in DB. I have tried `setInt()`, `setLong`, `setBigDecimal()`, the result is no different.
The database version is 12c. I want to know the reason.
My oracle version:

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

My JDBC version:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Implementation-Title: JDBC
Implementation-Version: 12.2.0.1.0
sealed: true
Repository-Id: JAVAVM_12.2.0.1.0_LINUX.X64_161213
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Specification-Title: JDBC
Created-By: 25.91-b14 (Oracle Corporation)
Specification-Version: 4.0
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Main-Class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Name: oracle/sql/
Sealed: false

Name: oracle/sql/converter/
Sealed: false

Name: oracle/jdbc/logging/annotations/
Sealed: false

Name: oracle/sql/converter_xcharset/
Sealed: false
```

Comment: What is the **exact** version of your database, and the exact version of the Oracle JDBC driver?

Comment: I am sorry for my English.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edits, you removed information and destroyed the edit I did that fixed formatting and typos.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers (or values that look like a `DATE`) in a varchar column? Most probably unrelated to the performance problem, but you should use an up-to-date driver. The driver version 10.x is obsolete and `classes12.jar` is intended for Java **1.2** not for any modern Java version.

Comment: Title is weak. Needs rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: I had tried new JDBC driver,The problem remains。

Answer (score 0):

Both of your queries can probably benefit from an index.  Taking the first version, which does not require a prepared statement:

```sql
SELECT KHDM
FROM T_KHZHYKQK
WHERE khdm = '10797684' AND zjzhlxdm = '0' AND rq BETWEEN '20191230' AND '20210104'
ORDER BY rq;
```

The following index might help this query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON T_KHZHYKQK (rq, zjzhlxdm, khdm);
```

This index covers the `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` and `SELECT` clauses completely.  You might try changing the order of the three columns in the index, though what I suggest is what I would probably try first.

Comment: my pluzzled is not the preformance, i want know the different of the sql, a whole String joined or the  dynamic parameters like ? . they all no index,why the first preformance is much better than second

Comment: @zhangkl Oh...well the second version is a prepared statement, and there is more overhead in sending the `?` parameter values over to the database.  Then, the database also has to do more work to bind those values to the statement.  This is one reason for the difference in performance.

Comment: no, i do not think so ,the reason you saied caused the gap is so big， it is totally unacceptable.

Comment: Well I _can_ accept it, especially if the prepared statement you are using has not been cached on the database and therefore must be compiled from scratch on demand.  Also, your benchmark and test may not be done correctly.

Comment: and i had tried like this   ```String sql = "select KHDM from T_KHZHYKQK where khdm= '10797684' and zjzhlxdm = '0' and rq >= '20191230' and rq <= '20210104' order by rq";
    String sql2 = "select KHDM from T_KHZHYKQK where khdm= ? and zjzhlxdm = ? and rq >= '20191230' and rq <= '20210104' order by rq";```   the result like this ```time1:293
time1:138
time1:145
time1:230
time1:230

time2:258
time2:91
time2:79
time2:81
time2:93```